# JS: func is not a function (onClick)

Tags: javascript, onclick, reactjs

I have main file with a function in it:

```
readFromInput = (value) => {
  console.log(value)
}
```

And I have an additional file with a function in it which allows me to render some button:

```
export default React.forwardRef(function(props,ref) {
    const {message,severity, flag, func}=props
    ......}
```

I want to call the onClick method in the last one with use of function from the first one:

```
<Button onClick={() => {func(value)}}>Ok</Button>
```

How should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your function and import it where you need it.

```
// main function

export const someFunction() => {
    console.log("functionstuff")
}

// some file 1
import { someFunction } from './components/someFunction'

// some file 2
import { someFunction } from './components/someFunction'
```

This is what makes React so awesome

Comment: "*This is what makes React so awesome*" yet you've shown a core JavaScript feature. React is not at all responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well it's late but for visitors first check if the ID

```js
//remove this for your function call globally
$(document).ready(function() {
  //your function

})
// make out side the function to make it call globally
function removeClass() {
  //your stuff 
  alert('hey your function is run')
}
```

```html
<p id='removeClass'>check previous html code if your function name match any html tag id in this case if your function name match with any id your function is not work (this is my case that reason function not runnning </p>

<button onclick="removeClass()">Remove Class</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

is with the same name maybe it's the cause of not working and remove $(document).ready(function() { your function}  to make it call globally and after that check it's run :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

export your function. or specify it while importing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).